# Sending ajax POST request receiving GET request

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using the following ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Editor.aspx/Page_LoadComplete",
    data: { "contentCheckCode": contents },
    type: "POST",
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Contents saved...");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

to send a post request to the code behind my webpage in order to save the contents of my tinyMCE editor to a file. My problem is that the code behind isn't receiving a POST request but rather a GET request, the following C# code highlighted this issue and also that the request had no contents:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) {
string test =Request.HttpMethod;
//listens for POST request
if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST"||Request.HttpMethod=="GET")
{
    String requestContents;
    using (Stream inputStream = Request.InputStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            requestContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this? I've searched for answers but can't seem to find anyone who had similar issues. I'm sure there's something I've done wrong or missed as I'm new to both jQuery and C#

Also as a new user on Stack Exchange I can't include images in my posts yet, but I tried to use the Network tab of the Chrome developer tools to shed some light on what was happening, the output of which can be found here: http://imgur.com/2LHuch8

EDIT: changed my ajax code to the following:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "Editor.aspx/PostHandle",
            data: { "content": contents },
            dataType: "text",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Contents saved...");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

and added the following method to my code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static String PostHandle(String content) {
        String test = content;
        return "Hello world";   
    }
```

and I placed a breakpoint at the above method but it's still not catching the request, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your webmethod should be having the syntax:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Page_LoadComplete(int id)
{
    ....
    return "hello";
 }
```

and similarly your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourPage.aspx/Page_LoadComplete",
    data: "{'id':'1'}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        //do something with data
    }
});
```

Comment: I changed my code accordingly but now every time I try to send the request I am being prompted for a username and password, my credentials are invalid apparently despite the fact that the page is on my local machine on which I have admin rights. I have not built any authentication into the web site yet and neither has the developer overseeing the project, there's also nothing in the web.config file about authentication. Is there anything built into System.Web.Services by default that I need to change to allow my page behind to receive post requests?

Comment: Also I placed a breakpoint at the method written to handle the request and it never stops at that point

Comment: is there any authentication need to be done? if yes then you need to set that in the headers in the ajax request

Comment: But I haven't written any and it's still prompting me for a password, it's now prompting me for a password when I try to load the page and before I've even sent the request, when I comment out the method declared with the WebMethod attribute this stops

Comment: Okay when I changed the dataType to text the passowrd prompts stopped, but the method still isn't catching the request, I'll paste my new code into the question

Comment: If no logic for password is written then I see no point why it is asking for password..yes code will help

Comment: Yeah I couldn't understand why that was happening at all, like I said though it stopped as soon as I changed the dataType from JSON to Text and removed the contentType header, the method I've written still isn't catching the request though